# Type safety when using ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

The second argument of the method `ViewGroup.addView` is a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. In many cases you'd want to use a subclass such as `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, but annoyingly there's no type-safety in the method  signature, so the following all compile and apparently work.

```
relativeLayout.addView(textView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

relativeLayout.addView(textView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

relativeLayout.addView(textView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This worries me slightly as it would be extremely easy to accidentally supply the wrong type. (I can't understand why it was designed this way, but that is not my question).

Obviously when a `ViewGroup` is laid out, all of the children's `LayoutParams` must at some point be cast to the appropriate type in order to read any extra rules. Can I be sure that for all of the standard subclasses of `ViewGroup` that all of these casts are checked casts (i.e. follow an `instanceof`), so that if I supply the wrong type I will never get a `ClassCastException` at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I be sure that for all of the standard subclasses of ViewGroup that all of these casts are checked casts (i.e. follow an instanceof), so that if I supply the wrong type I will never get a ClassCastException at runtime?

I guarantee you that is not the case, at least not in some situations. Getting `ClassCastExceptions` for providing the wrong `LayoutParams` type definitely happens, as I have had to answer a fair number of questions here on Stack Overflow when this happens to people.

That being said, in most cases, this exception is truly indicative of a coding error (versus something that a user might somehow trigger).

If your question is "does `addView()` on subclasses of `ViewGroup` check for the proper type?", the answer generally is "no", as classes like `RelativeLayout` do not override `addView()` but just use the inherited implementation from `ViewGroup`.

Comment: My question wasn't "does `addView()` on subclasses check for the proper type?", but "does the type get checked later when the `ViewGroup` is laid out?". However you've answered that as well. It's very annoying - I'm sure this could have been designed better so that these errors wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: "does the type get checked later when the ViewGroup is laid out?" -- no. Occasionally, a screwup survives, because it turns out the layout pass only needs stuff from a superclass (e.g., `MarginLayoutParams`). But, usually, you'll just blow up. "I'm sure this could have been designed better so that these errors wouldn't even compile" -- agreed. In their defense, comparatively few people roll this stuff themselves, preferring instead to inflate layout resources, and then this becomes far less of an issue.